# Dynamical rectangle plot c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I want to create a plot that dynamically displays active elements as rectangles. I have achieved a first version that is actually ok using OxyPlot.Annotations.RectangleAnnotation which I add to myPlotModel.Annotations, you can see it in the image hereafter:

> Example of wanted display
>   [image]

The thing is that after a while, the amount of drawn rectangles make the update not smooth as I update the shown timewindow (which is set to 15 seconds). I have already set a maximum of drawn elements that suffice to cover the displayed window (i.e. the rectangles get removed as they are too far in the past), but the rendering is still jerky. I draw the rectangles by allocating them to an equal fraction of the Y-axis, that is the third one from the top gets:

```
rowNumber= 3.0
minimumY = maximalY - maximalY / totalElements * rowNumber
maximumY = maximalY - maximalY / totalElements * (rowNumber + 1.0)
```

And the Y-axis is hidden.

My question:
Is there a smarter way of creating such a display that would be less computationally heavy, and therefore allow a smoother update? I do not have to stick to OxyPlot, it is simply the easiest way that I found to obtain what I wanted.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the answer to your question is "Yes".

There are a number of ways to do this.

You could have a vertical itemscontrol that had an itemscontrol in it's template. That could have a canvas as it's itemspresenter and you could bind canvas.top and canvas.left to properties in it's content. Template each into a rectangle and bind height and width.
And of course do something about the scale on the bottom  and the column of activity labels or whatever you want to call them there.
Unless you're using an absolutely ancient machine, that'd just fly.

It's quite a lot of work but it would probably be quicker to write that than to search through a load of alternative packages and decide which was optimal.